# Мгновенная обработка ввода текста в JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

Нужно, чтобы при вводе символа в `JTextField` мгновенно выполнялся код, замеряющий время ввода слова, важна каждая миллисекунда. Сейчас пытаюсь на главный `JFrame` повесить `KeyListener`, но думаю - это плохой способ, не синхронизированные потоки, все дела. Как можно узнать, что в поле ввели текст, как можно быстрее?

Comment: если вам важны миллисекунды, то лучше уменьшать количество компонент. каждая компонента добавляет задержку - надо вызвать все слушатели, перерисовать, поместить события в очередь и т.д.

Comment: Ну, у меня минимальное количество компонентов, а это `JFrame`, на котором отображается текст и немного информации, всё по минимуму, а так же сам `JTextField`. Так вот, можно создать скажем отдельный поток, который просто будет часто проверять содержимое поля, но это ни есть хорошо, да и к тому же, информация о времени нажатия будет не очень точна. Вот бы код выполнялся только тогда, когда в текстовое поле добавляется новый символ, но как? Пока ищу.

Comment: если посмотрите исходный код, то увидите сколько действий происходит. Все они вносят задержку. Если сделаете на "голом" AWT, то будет быстрее.

Comment: Не понимаю вас. Кто такой "голый" AWT? Предлагаете реализовать только окно а все остальные элементы сделать самостоятельно, дабы не использовать лишние проверки, которые есть в стандартных компонентах?

Comment: Swing это надстройка над AWT

Comment: Я всё равно вас не понимаю, мне проще на код взглянуть. Не могли бы вы дать ссылку на доступную для новичка статью, либо показать пример подобной реализации?

Comment: обратите внимание на официальную по Swing и AWT. JTextField - это Swing, TextField - AWT.

Comment: Вот ещё что, у меня прозрачное окно, AWT поддерживает подобный функционал?

Comment: да. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setOpacity-float-

Comment: Спасибо за совет, обязательно прочту и буду стараться лучше оптимизировать программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение, возможно не самое элегантное, но в моём случае сработало и полностью отвечает требованиям.

Создаём свой `KeyListener` содержащий интерфейс `KeyListener`:

```
private static class KListener implements KeyListener
{
    private String str = "";

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
            {if (!str.equals("")) str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);}
        else if (code != KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT && code != KeyEvent.VK_ALT &&
                 code != KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK && code != KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL &&
                 code != KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && code != KeyEvent.VK_TAB &&
                 code != KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS && code != KeyEvent.VK_CONTEXT_MENU)
                     str += e.getKeyChar();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

Если нажимаем `Backspace`, то стираем последний символ, иначе добавляем символ введённый с клавиатуры в текст, если, конечно, это не функциональная клавиша (все функциональные клавиши проверять не стал, ибо не было нужды, да и так получилось немаленькое нагромождение в коде).

Осталось на наш `JTextField` повесить `KeyListener`:

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KListener(this));
```

Всё, теперь в переменной `str` будет храниться текст, который содержится и в `JTextField` и его можно обработать с минимальной задержкой.

Comment: если нужно отсеивать только буквы/цифры - можно делать это через проверку
`char ch = e.getKeyChar();
if ((ch>'a')&&(ch<'z')){str += ch}`

Comment: Нужно отсеивать все буквы, цифры, символы, всё, кроме функциональных клавиш. В общем то, что печатается в `JTextField`, должно содержаться в переменной `str`. Знаете какой-нибудь более производительный способ, чтобы отсеять только функциональные клавиши?

Answer (score 0):

если хочешь обрабатывать текст при вставке, стоит поиграться с этим:

```
((AbstractDocument)textComponent.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter(){
@Override
public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
super.insertString(fb, offset, modifyString(string), attr);
}
@Override
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
super.replace(fb, offset, length, modifyString(text), attrs);
}
});
```

Comment: Сравнил ваш метод со своей реализацией, ваш метод медленнее на несколько миллисекунд, обычно на 1-3. Разница конечно не существенная, но мой метод мне кажется проще, потому оставлю его. Спасибо, что подкинули интересный способ реализации, возможно пригодится в будущем.